# Tor Browser won't launch after torrc file edited for hidden services

Tags: configuration, onion-services, error

I'm a beginner who need a little help. I got stuck while i was trying to setup my hidden service.

I'm on a Mac (EL Capitan) running Windows 7 on Parallels Desktop virtual machine. I have my wampserver 2.5 running quite nice (honestly i have a little issue: if i place my site to the www folder it wont load for the localhost command in the browser, only when i give the exact location like `localhost.index.html`, i don't think its connected to my tor problem :) ) or? :)

Tor Browser run just fine, but when i add this line:

```
# Hidden Service
HiddenServiceDir C:\Users\UserName\tor_service
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

I got an error message:

> Tor unexpectedly exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you restart Tor, the Tor Browser will not able to reach any websites. If the problem persists, please send a copy of your Tor Log to the support team. Restarting Tor will not close your browser tabs.

If i make any changes in the `torrc` file, this problem occurs. When i delete the added lines, the problem disappear.

Any idea?

Comment: ohh one thing! Someone said it might be a permission issue, so Tor cant create the file, but im lost at this point.

Comment: Try running `tor.exe --verify-config` and see which line it thinks is the problem. (I can't immediately tell what the problem is... ) But yes, check that `UserName` has permissions to run Tor in the first place. (i.e. This user must match the user that downloaded and extracted/installed the Tor folder.)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, however i couldnt run tor.exe --verify-config in the command prompt either. it gives me the same result as i mentioned. Im still confused by this permission issue. If i can run tor with the original settings in the torrc file, why i cant do again after i edited it a little with the hidden services lines?

Comment: Because you're adding a new location - `C:\Users\UserName\tor_service` - that Tor must be able to read. If the permissions on `C:\Users\UserName\tor_service` don't allow read/execute, then Tor will struggle. So `--verify config` gives no output at all?

Comment: on windows I found the answer here: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/16015/17207

Comment: Are there any suggestions as to which linux permissions will solve this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21053)

Comment: I have solved it now. It seems like, in mac, I tried to edit it using torrc file in TorBrowser-Data directory. This is wrong. You must let this file be and edit the one at /etc/ (find it apart from the one in Applications.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the directory `C:\Users\UserName\tor_service` and tor has read, write, and execute permissions.

Comment: Thank You very much for the help! The permission issue is solved and its working!
Bless you all! :)

Answer (score 0):

You edited the wrong torrc file. Instead of editing the one in TorBrowser-Data, try to find another one in /etc/ bin. Regardless, I fixed mine by editing the one there.