# windows: Tor browser error after editing torrc file

Tags: configuration

The questions ([1](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10158/tor-browser-wont-launch-after-torrc-file-edited-for-hidden-services) [2](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10158/tor-browser-wont-launch-after-torrc-file-edited-for-hidden-services)) about it are for mac OS. I'm strugling with windows 10.

I downloaded tor brownser and added that to the torrc file (I want to use it with scrapy)

```
    ControlPort 9051
    HashedControlPassword password_XYZ
```

(before I launch the cmd `tor --hash-password "password_XYZ"` )

But now the brownser doesn't work anymore. `Tor unexpectedly exited.`

(I tried to use the "Tor Expert Bundle on Windows" (comes without brownser) but I did not find any torrc files on it so I don't know how to use it to add the code above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HashedControlPassword` line is the issue.

```
HashedControlPassword password_XYZ
```

When you run `tor --hash-password` you should get output like this

```
$ tor --hash-password password_XYZ
16:54C092A84F51545F600F6DEC3CEC93D16DE4C941FE12686CD10B8F4F3E
```

Then you want to put the output into the HashedControlPassword torrc line so it looks like this

```
HashedControlPassword 16:54C092A84F51545F600F6DEC3CEC93D16DE4C941FE12686CD10B8F4F3E
```

On Windows, the tor.exe process won't display output properly on the `cmd.exe` terminal. A work around for this is to pipe it into `more`, e.g.

```
tor.exe --hash-password password_XYZ | more
```

This should then display the output, giving you the hashed password to put into the `torrc`

Comment: thanks! I could get the `16:string...` using `tor.exe --hash-password password_XYZ | more` and addd it to the torrc but it still doesn't work: the torrc look like https://i.imgur.com/Bld0cbF.png ( I did `tor --service remove` and then `tor --service install -options ControlPort 9051` to relaunch it. I tried to reboot the computer but no luck).

Comment: Ah, so you've added the service. Tor Browser launches it's own copy of Tor, if they're both using the same torrc then you'll already have a copy of Tor running and the one Tor Browser tries to launch will not be able to bind to the same port as the already running service. You should try removing the service, it's not required on Windows with Tor Browser.

Comment: yes, you were right launching `tor --service remove` did solve the problem. Oh man that was vicious. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: but actually it created a new problem! My python code doesnt work anymore! I actually edited the torrc file so to communicate with python stem. I opened the port by using `tor --service install -options ControlPort 9051`. So I guess I need the service right? or is it possible to open the port without the `service install` if so how? (I tried `>tor  -options ControlPort 9051` but it did not work)

Comment: Tor Browser opens a control port on port `9151` by default, if you use that in your python code it should work.

Comment: I don't understand why I need the `tor --service install -options ControlPort 9051` but it only works with it. I read here that "`Normal Tor installation does not enable the ControlPort by default`", what do you think?
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/33875657/1486850

Comment: Tor Browser is different, if you're starting Tor from Tor Browser parts of it are already configured so it will create a control port on port 9151 and you should be able to just replace `with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:` with `with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:`, `socks5://127.0.0.1:9050` with `socks5://127.0.0.1:9150` and start Tor Browser and it will work, also you don't need the password authentication option since it will use cookie auth.